# im getting assert.equal is not a function while using japa testing framework

Tags: node.js, testing, japa

I'm getting "assert.equal is not a function" while using japa testing framework

The error:
[image: photo of the error]

The configuration:
[image: photo of config]

I'm expecting the test runs as expected, but it keeps throwing an error. I made sure to install assert when I installed japa from the command line.

I've tried deleting node modules and re-installing, still says the same thing.